# How to sort dataset.table[0] then get the top 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, sorting, dataview

I'm adding an auto increment column (called "rowNum") to my table and it's working good, after that I use this code to sort datatable rows :

```
DataView dv = MyDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "columnName DESC";
```

where columnName is one of my columns (not the auto increment one).

Now,The problem is:
when I want to get the top 10 rows I use this code :

```
dv.RowFilter = "rowNum <= 10";
```

The result is not what I want, because when I do `dv.Sort` the rowNum shuffled (becomes in wrong order).

How can I get top 10 rows after sorting rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer LINQ for stuff like this.  Instead, I use System.Linq and write:

```
var rows = MyDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
   .OrderByDescending(r => r["columnName"]) 
   .Take(10);
```

and then just bind to "rows".

Comment: thanx a lot for your help but do you think if this way will do good on rows more than 1000 ?.

Comment: Yes.  It should work at least as well as the DataView solution.

Answer (score 0):

if add .Take(10) in AsEnumerable() line is not working. but if add second line as mentioned below is working.

```html
var Rows = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() 
orderby row["CostPerVeteran"] descending
select row);

dtChart = Rows.Take(10).CopyToDataTable();
```